# Too much request to a web service

Tags: asp.net, iis, messenger

I wrote a messenger in a web application. i use a asmx web service to receive all request and give response according to type of request. (sending and  watching incoming messages are based on pooling system. **i do not use reverse ajax**) I have a problem when i put my source code on the IIS 7.0. The problem is, when number of user increase (more than 80 request per second) IIS will not response any more requests and also my web site will be down.
Is there any specific configuration with IIS which i have to do?

Thanks

Comment: It probably has to do something with your service. You should show what it does then we might find a solution to your problem. The answer to your question is: there is no specific configuration for IIS. You write about pooling: could be that you pool is used.

Comment: I use **dictionary** to implement my messenger memory. i think the problem is my **dictionary** because i use **lock** for concurrent thread management.
Now I'm going to change dictionary to **ConcurrentDictionary** and removing all **lock**.

Comment: It could help if you show your code. lock itself is not a problem eather unless you run into a deadlock.

Comment: I solved my problem using **ConcurrentDictionary**.
the problem was using Thread Synchronization in my code. too much request were in Queue to be respond but IIS could not respond them. 
by concurrent dictionary i could solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: must have been kind of deadlock then. Great that you solved the problem.